# How to prevent Express.js piping file in quotes?

Tags: node.js, express

Hopefully an easy one to fix: I'm piping a file from S3 to the browser, it's working fine on OSX, but on Windows the filename is wrapped in quotes when the file is downloaded.

```
file = "filename.zip";

request("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/" + file)
.pipe(res.set("Content-Type", "application/zip").set("Content- 
Disposition", "inline; filename='" + file + "'"));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That code is not valid, can you post the exact code?

Comment: Updated, although I've obscured the real URL & filename.